# How can we execute pytest ,Test classes or set of Test functions within conftest.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Consider we have within same root folder, we have **conftest.py , setup.py ,teardown.py and testsomething.py**

```
    #conftest.py
        ----------------------
    import pytest
    import setup // from setup import Test_Setup
    import teardown // from teardown import Test_Teardown

    @pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
    def t(request):
        t = getT()
        request.addfinalizer(t.cleanup)
        return t

    @pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
    def setup(t):
        // Here I want to execute class "Test_Setup" as pytest class

    @pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
    def teardown(t):
        yield
        // Here I want to execute  class "Test_TearDown"as pytest class

     #setup.py
    ----------------------
    class Test_Setup:

        def test_creation(self, t):
         //test codes

        def test_setp1(self, t):
         //test codes

        def test_step2(self, t):
         //test codes

     #teardown.py
    ----------------------
    class Test_Teardown:

        def test_Reset(self,t):
           // some cleanup code

 #testsomething.py
    ----------------------
    class Test_Something:

        def test_1(self,t):
           // some cleanup code
         def test_2(self,t):
           // some cleanup code
```

we know before running test class and its function in testsomething.py pytest will run fixture **setup** and finally **teardown** defined in **conftest.py**

---

Problem is within these **setup** and **teardown** fixtures I want to run those pytest test classes defined in setup.py and teardown.py respectively.

**Please Note** : Those Test class execution should be executed as pytest Test class not like general class instantiation and call member function scenario and also we cannot touch **testsometing.py** definition, which means it should not related/imported with **setup.py** or **teardown.py**

If you can provide a solution for python 2.7 that would be really helpful.
Thank you for the considering.

Comment: Why do you want that? Setup and teardown are not meant for test execution, as they do not provide the necessary context yet.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for the information.